Как записать pid процесса для определенного порта в переменную?
Как перевести в скрипт следующую мысль, возми например порт 8081 и запиши в переменную pid процесса.

Unix & Linux SO: What process is listening on a port?; Baeldung: Finding the PID of the Process Using a Specific Port

Благодарю. Вот этой командой можно  fuser 9082/tcp и я понимаю что есть разные утилиты показывающие и выдающие те или иные параметры, как именно выданный результат записать в переменную в скрипте вот в чём вопрос.
